# How are api keys stored securely in mobile apps?

Tags: api, security, ionic-framework, api-key, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to build a woocommerce frontend mobile app (ionic) using the woocommerce-api.

I have to make the api key be able to read AND write so that people can place orders.

The api key is used to get any data from the store (backend) like product images, names, etc...

If someone got a hold on the api secret key he can do whatever he wants to my woocommerce store, erase products, add products, or anything.

#### The following is the part I dont understand:

If I store my keys on a server, and write a method to retrieve them whenever a user uses my app, what is stopping anyone from reverse engineering my app and using the calling the same method to retrieve my api key and then proceeding to do whatever they want?

Example 1 (api stored in client-side)

```
1- hacker reads my source code.
2- hacker reads my api secret key.
3- hacker writes a fake app to mess with my store.
```

Example 2 (api stored in server)

```
1- hacker reads my source code.
2- hacker finds out my function "GetApiFromServer()"
3- hacker uses write a fake app with the same GetApiFromServer() function.
4- hacker messes with my store.
```

What is the difference? is there something I am missing?

Comment: This has been asked (and answered) here several times previously. You can see some of those posts over there (**===>>>>**) in the Related list, and they were displayed for you as potential duplicates when you posted this. Please do some research before asking a question here. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to understand the concept of it.
I read more than posts and they mostly say use secure server, use encryption.
I wanted to understand how it would matter, if a hacker could just use the same functions I used to get the api key, encrypted or not.

Comment: And that's discussed in those other posts. Again, please do some research before asking here.

Comment: sry i clicked enter by mistake, please read my edit

Comment: Spend some time searching on [security.se], which has many discussions about encryption and security (the reasons for its existence).

Comment: Thanks, I will.
problem is the key concept eludes me, also, people put links to useful services that can be an eye opener, and thats all I need, an eye opener so I can grasp the concept.

also just to point i am 100% self taught and I am 100% sure that I missed a lot of programing principles while studying.